# Redirecting Standard Input/Output in RPyC 3

Tags: python, printing, client-server, rpyc

As explained [here](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/howto.html), redirecting the stdio/stdin is very simple with RPyC 2. This means that 'print' commands executed in the server, will display the printed string on the client side.

RPyC 2, as explained [here](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/tut3.html#tut3), is un-secured and is not recommended, but I couldn't find anywhere how can I print on the client side with RPyC 3.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Edit:

For example, this is the code to my server:

```
import rpyc
import time
from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer

class TimeService(rpyc.Service):
    def exposed_print_time(self):
        for i in xrange(10):
            print time.ctime()
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = ThreadedServer(TimeService, port=8000)
    t.start()
```

and in my client, I run:

```
conn = rpyc.connect("192.168.1.5")
conn.root.print_time()
```

my goal is to get the time every second (or anything else I want to print) in the client's stdout, but the client just hangs and the time is only printed in the server.

Comment: Did you went through tutorials? Did it work? If not, what went wrong or what you did not understand?

Comment: @Jan Vlcinsky I went through the tutorials and it all worked, but they don't explain how to redirect the output to the client. After completing the tutorials and printing on the server, the print output is shown in the server only, and I want it to show in the client

Comment: It would be great if you show some code. Do you want to execute something on a client and see it printed on a server? Will anybody have a chance to see such a printout? Or you expect the server to react by some action to it? What action?

Comment: @JanVlcinsky I've edited my server's code to my post

Comment: wouldn't it be much simpler to do `print conn.root.get_time()` instead?

Comment: @shx2 - I would look like that, yes, but then I'll have to implement some logic in the client side. e.g. in the code above, to do a loop that sleeps and calls get_time() 10 times. I don't want any logic to be on the client side - only to call a function and that the server would do the rest. It's possible in RPyC 2. The question is - is that possible in RPyC 3?

Answer (score 0):

you could use return on server side:

```
#on server
def exposed_test(self):
   return "this is test"

#on client
conn.root.test()
>>> 'this is test'
```